# Use NPM to install a codebase for development

Tags: node.js, git, npm

Using `npm install foo` results in:

1. `foo` being installed to `./node_modules/foo`
2. No version control repo.

Yet, since NPM generally knows the version control repo location, it would be convenient to be able to do `npm start-dev foo` and get:

1. Check out the repo for package `foo` into `./foo`
2. Then `npm install`.

Is there any way to achieve that? The current workflow involves looking up the NPM repo to find the repo location, then checking that out, then doing `npm install`.

Comment: I don't think there is such a shortcut at the moment, but it seems quite handy.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is an NPM module, [`npm-clone`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-clone) that does just this.

```
$ npm install -g npm-clone

$ npm-clone install foo
Cloning into 'foo'...
WARN engine npm@1.4.29: wanted: {"node":">=0.8","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"3.5.3"})
...
```